# How to pass a variable into jquery's $.post success callback function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want jquery to keep track of multiple $.posts and know which one it's referring to on success. I'm running this app on a really slow internet connection, so if there's a pile of these posts, I want to know which post was successful. With my current code, it seems $el is unset in the callback function

```
function go(d){
    $el = $("[data-id='"+ d +"']");

    $.post(
        'receive.php',
        {tickets:t},
        function(req, err){ 
            $el.removeClass("checked");
    });
}
```

Comment: You should declare your variables.

Comment: If you declare a variable inside a function, it will only be available in that function and in all its children functions. So you'll need to declare it in global scope in order to make it available globally. A common (but not perfectly sane) practice is to use the `window` object to store data. If you don't polute it much (use a single variable for all your storage), it's fine. Another option is to use more modern techniques such as [`localStorage`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webstorage.html#dom-localstorage). However, it's not yet fully supported.

Comment: I see no `t` anywhere, where does it hide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest reading up on [scope in javascript](https://www.sitepoint.com/demystifying-javascript-variable-scope-hoisting/). By simply making your `$el = $("[data-id...")` variable local to the function (`var $el = ...`), it should remain unique to the scope that each `$.post()` call is made in, ensuring that the correct element is updated in the callback.