# Passing variables into jquery's $.post done callback function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42421375/how-to-pass-a-variable-into-jquerys-post-success-callback-function)
But that solution creating a variable locally doesn't work for me.

My case is:

```
handleSubmit() {
    var posting = $.post(this.props.url, {...});
    posting.done(function() {
        window.location.href = `/frontend/${this.props.value}`;
    });
}
```

Since the callback function doesn't have access to `this`, how should I pass `this` into the callback? If I'm not going to use Ajax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3 ways

Old school - think old IE before IE9

```
var _this = this;

posting.done(function() {
    window.location.href = `/frontend/${_this.props.value}`;
});
```

Middle school - think IE9 thru IE 11

```
posting.done(function() {
    window.location.href = `/frontend/${this.props.value}`;
}.bind(this));
```

New School - any real browser

```
posting.done(() => {
    window.location.href = `/frontend/${this.props.value}`;
});
```

Considering you're using template literals, you're safe to use the "new school" method

Comment: I'm kind of new to JavaScript. Would you mind explain a little bit what is the different between `function() {}` and `() => {}`? Why `() => {}` this way can access to `this`? Thank you for your time.

Comment: *explain a little* arrow notation `() => {}` *does not have binding to it's own `this`*, rather *Arrow functions establish `this` based on the scope the Arrow function is defined within* - [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) documentation explains it in great detail - I've lifted what I've said directly from there :p